# Proof of uncertainty principle in Nielsen and Chuang

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, notation

I read the proof of uncertainty principle in Nielsen and Chuang.

There is something I don't understand. They use operators $A$ and $B$ respectively as $P - \langle P \rangle$ and $Q - \langle Q \rangle$. As I understand it, $A$ and $B$ are the values of $P$ and $Q$ minus their expectation value. But for instance $A$ is an operator, and $P - \langle P \rangle$ is a scalar. How can we substract a scalar from an operator and get an operator? I think there is something I'm missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an implicitly written identity operator, e.g.,
$$P - \langle P \rangle\hat {\bf 1}, $$

Comment: Well that's answers my question, thanks !